# simple screen recorder is not recording sound on ubuntu 21.04

Tags: 21.04, sound-recorder

i am using ubuntu 21.04
while recording screen playing a video on youtube.
only video gets recorded no audio from youtube or anything playing on screen is recorded (only video no sound).
while logging i use ubuntu on xorg.
i have tried almost all combinations from
setting>sound>input.
also kazam software is not recording the sound.

Comment: Which software are you using to record? Please edit to add that information. BTW, you can download youtube videos with youtube-dl (`pip3 install --user youtube-dl`), you don't need to screen record them.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1366891/edit) the question instead of adding a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer here
https://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/troubleshooting/#no-sound-when-recording-the-speakers-with-pulseaudio

If no sound is recorded, make sure the monitor channel is not muted. To do this, go to the "Input devices" tab in PulseAudio Volume Control, select "Show: All input devices" and make sure the "Mute audio" button of the monitor channel is not enabled. (credit goes to 'scrawl' for figuring this out)[image]